# Eclipse Mars clean build and move war to Jboss deployment directory

Tags: maven, build, jboss, m2e

I'm using eclipse Mars with maven integration plugin and configure JBoss EAP 7.0 server in Eclipse Mars.

I follow the maven build configuration [guide](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html) and successfully build and generate war in target directory.

Is that possible, use maven build run > "clean install" to create a new project.war in target directory. Meanwhile, project.war will upload to %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments directory. I trying binding the build and export process at the same time.

I trying add following configuration in pom.xml but not working.

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <webappDirectory>D:\jboss-eap-7.0.0\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments\</webappDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Or

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <outputDirectoryD:\jboss-eap-7.0.0\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments\</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Or

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
            <target>
               <copy file="D:\workspace\project\target\project.war"
                                    todir="D:\jboss-eap-7.0.0\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments\" />
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

**Result:**

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 among available goals testCompile, compile, help -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tried, I decide use an alternative solution. 
What's I need basically compile a war file and deploy to Jboss server.

I write a batch job as following to archive same goal.
After I change on source code from Eclipse and I will run this batch job to trigger the change.

**Batch Job**

```
SET WORKSPACE=D:\workspace\project\
SET JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT=D:\jboss-eap-7.0.0\jboss-eap-7.0\standalone\deployments\

cd /D %WORKSPACE%
echo %WORKSPACE%

call mvn clean package

xcopy /y %WORKSPACE%\target\*.war %JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT%

echo Move war from %WORKSPACE% to %JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT%

pause
```

This batch Job will compile new war file and copy war to JBoss deployment directory, server will automatically do hot-deploy if detect any update on war.